# How to modify the registration form?

Tags: forms, users

I need some help adding text to the bottom of the registration form. I've never modified the registration form before and I did not set up this site.  Bootstrap Modal is being used for the form. Here is a screen capture of it:

[image]

The content needs a check box that must be checked for the submit button to work. Is there a module that can help, or, how do I locate this form to do some modifications?

Answer (score 1):

You can always alter any form by hook_form_alter,in your case it would be somewhat closer to following

```
// Implements hook_form_form_id_alter().
function my_module_name_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state) {
  $form['help_text'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'Your help text will go here',
    '#weight' => $form['mail']['#weight'] + 1; // Or could be a fix value.
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Where would use this hook?

Comment: you have to implement this hook in custom module.(https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules)

Comment: No.  I've never implemented a hook in the custom module.

Comment: So, in order to modify this form, I'll have to create a custom module?  That is something I've been wanting to get to.  Thanks for the link.  I'll read through it.  Any other advise?

Comment: Thank you, Arpitr, I will try this.  I'm working on other parts of the site right now, but, I'll definitely implement this when I get back to it.